# How do I accept a list of tensors in a placeholder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do the following:

```
out = sess.run(operation, feed_dict={x: x_value, , y: y_value})
```

Somewhere in the model definition, I have used this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 3))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 3))
operation = some_function(x, y)
```

where `x` and `y` are images. How do I rewrite my code so that I can evaluate multiple `y`s with a single `x`. I want to do something like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 3))
y = []
x = []
for _y in y:
    operation = some_function(x, _y)
    z.append(operation)
```

Right now I just do this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 3))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, None, 3)) #add extra dimension
z = tf.unstack(tf.map_fn(some_function, y))
```

But the problem is when I do that, `tf.unpack` throws an error says its not aware of the size of y and fails.

This is solved by doing this, where I initialize `y`'s 0 index with the total number of images.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 3))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, None, None, 3)) #add extra dimension
z = tf.unstack(tf.map_fn(some_function, y))
```

and I eval the values using:

```
y_values = np.stack([y_value1, y_value2])
out = sess.run(operation, feed_dict={x: x_value, , y: y_values })
```

Ideally I want this to be variable and me not having to initialize the value of the placeholder. Lets say I want it to do a weighted sum of all the different `y` values. Each time just 1`y` or 5`y`s, etc.

Comment: How you are doing it, adding an additional first `None` dimension, is the right way to do it. However, you should not try to unpack the result of `tf.map_fn`, but instead have `z` as another tensor with the additional first dimension too. Why do you need to unpack it?

Comment: I need to unpack it because the later part of the code takes `z` which needs to be a list of tensors to iteratively process it. I can't change that part of the code.

Comment: I see. The problem is, when you are creating the graph you do not know how many inputs you will have, so the idea of getting the list of unpacked tensors cannot really be done at this point, because it would not make sense; you cannot have a list, with a fixed number of elements, to represent something which you do not yet know the size of. You will have to either reconsider your later code or have a fixed number of inputs. The closest thing I can think of is having a max number of inputs and then "pad" the rest with zero-valued tensors (or whatever), but I'm not sure that would be useful.

Comment: I get it. I am also looking for an alternative solution without `tf.map_fn`. Is it possible to create `y` as a placeholder that accepts a list value, so that I don't have to np.stack it? So that I can iterate over it to generate `z` without using `tf.unpack`

Comment: In your example, if you just pass `y: [y_value1, y_value2]` in your `feed_dict` it will work the same, because TensorFlow will interpret that list as a tensor, but `y` will still be a tensor. It is still the same situation, since you don't know its size, you cannot iterate over it. About `tf.map_fn`, it depends on what `some_function` does, but yes, it is preferable to make `some_function` process all the elements at once instead of using `tf.map_fn` with a per-element function. But, as I said, how to do that (if it is possible) depends on the body of `some_function`.